# Bash: read stdin from file and write stdout to file

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to run an app (let's say `top`) so it will read from a file for stdin and write to another file from stdout.

Currently I have

```
mkfifo stdin.pipe
(tail -f stdin.pipe) | top
```

which works as expected, as I can then `echo` something to that file and top will receive it.
But I'm unable to redirect the output of top.
How can I achieve this?

EDIT:

Ok, let's scratch top.
I'm testing with this:

```
cat test.sh

echo Say something
read something
echo you said $something
```

Comment: Are you sure `top` reads from `stdin`?  Mine doesn't.  You can redirect output from `top` using the `-b` (batch) option: `top -n 1 -b > gash`

Comment: @cdarke I'm sorry, you're right. I was making tests with another app. top doesn't work the same way. Is there a way I can map stdin and stdout to files and use them to control a cli app?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Let's forget about `top`, that appears to be a red herring.

To map stdin or stdout to files, you can use redirection:

```
some_program < input_file          # Redirects stdin

another_program > output_file      # Redirects stdout
```

or even:

```
yet_another  < input_file > output_file
```

Comment: Is this async or sync? I just tested it with a 2 lines bash that will say "Hi", wait for input and then say "Bye". I was able to see the output in the output_file after I redirected something to the input_file (aka, when the app finished running)

Comment: If you are commuicating between programs then use an anonymous pipe, it will be more efficient than using a temporary file.  Depends what you mean by sync/async in this context, but all shell IO is buffered.  The buffer is flushed and the file is closed after each redirection, but you can get issues if a program is reading while one is writing (to a file, not a pipe).

Comment: The problem is that I'm trying to control a CLI app from PHP so I can't save the handle to the pipe, that's why I need to be able to read/write to/from files. How can I force output to be flushed instead of going to buffer?

Comment: Use a named pipe instead of a file, you can redirect to a named pipe just as if it was a file (um, actually, it is a file).  You can also read a named pipe from PHP just as if it was a text file.

Comment: are you sure that this will work with the example script I posted in my question? (the edit part). I just created mkfifo ```in``` and ```out``` and I ran my script. I expected to get ```Say something``` after ```cat out``` but I didn't get anything.

Comment: How to take input until reaches the end of the file and then come out of script automatically. I am in infinite loop and it does not come out of loop when EOF reached.

Answer (score 8):

> Is there a way I can map stdin and stdout to files and use them to control a cli app?

It sounds like you are looking for [coprocesses](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Coprocesses.html), added to Bash in 4.0.

```
coproc cat                    # Start cat in background
echo Hello >&${COPROC[1]}     # Say "Hello" to cat
read LINE <&${COPROC[0]}      # Read response
echo $LINE                    # cat replied "Hello"!
```

Before 4.0 you had to use two named pipes to achieve this.

Comment: Interesting addition!