# Compile java program

Tags: java, compilation, command, pipe, line

when compiling a java program you normally use `java programName`.
What does the below line mean?

`java BinarySearch whitelist.txt < input.txt`   What are the 2 txt files doing (is it input output files) what is the < mean

Thanks

Comment: Don't you use `javac fileName` for compiling?

Comment: sry for the confusion, what does  whitelist.txt < input.txt  mean in the below BinarySearch compilation                                                                                                        java BinarySearch whitelist.txt < input.txt

Comment: `java JavaProgramName`  used to run a program not compile.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java (or compilation, for that matter). It says you want to run a program `java` with two arguments, "BinarySearch" and "whitelist.txt", with the program's stdin coming from the contents of the file input.txt. This is all bash (or zsch) functionally, not Java.

Comment: so the stdIn is coming from input.txt and then the output is written to whitelist.txt. is that correct?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680530/bash-read-stdin-from-file-and-write-stdout-to-file

Comment: No, the input is coming from input.txt, and there's no way to know how whitelist.txt is used. It all depends on what BinarySearch.main does with the first element of its String array

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the `<` character will redirect the standard input to the `input.txt` file. This means that `System.in` will represent the file, rather than the console input. Using the `>` character would instead redirect the standard output to the file, so that `System.out` will represent the file, rather than the console output. These characters are not interpreted by the java virtual machine, but by the shell.

Since there is no special character in front of `whitelist.txt`, it just acts as an argument to the java program, and will be stored in `args[0]` (or whatever the arguments variable is named in the program).

By the way, using the `java program` command will not compile the java file, it will instead run the compiled class file. To compile a java file, use the `javac file.java` command.

Answer (score 0):

The **args* following **BinarySearch** are inputs into the program.

As shown in the documentation for the code, `<` is being used for redirect from **StdIn**.

[image]