# Python input function length limit

Tags: python, python-3.x, jwt

I want to use the input function in python3 to ask the user a jwt token.

Unfortunately, I'm reaching the length limit of this function (I think).

The length of my jwt token is `1130 characters`

When I'm pasting my token into the input, I'm facing a blocker and its truncated.

Do you see any workaround or another way to do this ?

```py
    # if config is empty, load using input() functions
    if not cdp_token:
        cdp_token = input("Token JWT Empty! Please Enter your cdh api token (https://mysite/profile):\n")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How big can the input to the input() function be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40598483/how-big-can-the-input-to-the-input-function-be)

Comment: Not really as the limit is very light in my case, only 1130 characters! we don't reach python string limit with only a few characters, and If the string comes from my config file, I was able to manipulate it easy with the same length. The issue is located at input level function

Answer (score 1):

You can use concept of hashing. Try hashing your token to something small, may be using SHA or any standard algorithm. When you check the token from database/repository you can hash that db token as well and compare it in your function. I think this can be a good approach.