# How can I enlarge the python input()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, io

I just use `input()` in a .py file. I input many words in it, but it is always stuck after 1023 characters. I believe the limit in input() is larger than 1023. I want to input more words into it, and how can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Can you put all the text into a file and read the file instead?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40598522/2681662