# c++ command line argmuent not printing out values from text file

Tags: c++

I have a file with numers I am trying to open,however when I run 
my file it does not print the values and just gives me 0.

code:

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
 for (int count=0; count < argc; ++count)
    std::cout << count << " " << argv[count] << '\n';
  return 0;
 }
```

File:

```
        198      4          12
```

And the output I get when i run ./text < file.txt
is 0.

Comment: argv is an array of pointers to char. Length is stored in argc argument.

Comment: How would I go about extracting the numbers from the text file?

Comment: You don't even get 0 ./text? The file should be going to standard in, not to the command line.

Comment: The file name has to go to the command line (requirement)

Comment: Sorry. I'm unclear. if you execute ./text < file.txt then the contents of file.txt should show up in standard in and be readable with cin. More reading here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680530/bash-read-stdin-from-file-and-write-stdout-to-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'are trying to redirect file's content to INPUT stream, try this code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string str;
    std::stringstream ss;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, str)) {
        ss << str << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << ss.str();
}
```

Comment: This made a lot more sense, Thank you,the input now works!

Answer (score 1):

The `< file.txt` syntax you're using is essentially simulating keyboard input, i.e., an input stream traditionally known/accessed as `std::cin` in C++ or `stdin` in C.

More background on that topic: [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514/184038)

Your code is trying to iterate over command-line arguments, which is neither pulling input from `std::cin`, nor is it accessing the input with any awareness that a file is involved.

If you want, or need, to extract data from `std::cin` (which is consistent with your `<` syntax), check out the following reference with examples of how that's done: [std::cin, std::wcin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin).

If you want to process input as a file, try this reference with example: [std::basic_ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream).

(Note that this latter example deals with a binary file, but you can make appropriate changes for your text file.)